# form_for passing in class as option

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to give my form a class. Looking through the docs, it doesn't seem like there's a way to do this, and that you can only pass in things like name like this

`form_for @changeset, @action, [name: :search], fn f -> %>`

Is there any way to pass in class as an option so my form html element can have a class? Perhaps like this?

`form_for @changeset, @action, [class: 'form-horizontal'], fn f ->`

I was digging through the phoenix source code but can't seem to find anything on it.

Answer (score 18):

It was breaking because I was using single quotes rather than double quotes for `'form-horizontal'`. Single quotes habits from my Ruby programming...